# Can't connect to vm when connected to vpn

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, vpn

I'm running VM on Ubuntu with Vagrant and VirtualBox. It has private network on 192.168.56.101. When I connect to VPN (SonicWALL NetExtender), I can't connect to VM anymore. On Windows the command ROUTE CHANGE 192.168.56.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.56.1 METRIC 300 solves the problem, but I tried to do something like this on Ubuntu (route add -net 192.168.56.0 gw 192.168.56.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 metric 300) and it's not working there.

Host routes without VPN:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp8s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp9s0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
```

Host routes with VPN:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.144   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp8s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
128.0.0.0       192.168.0.144   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     192.168.0.144   255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
192.0.2.1       192.168.0.144   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ppp0
192.0.2.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.144   255.255.252.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     192.168.0.144   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp9s0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp8s0
192.168.56.0    192.168.0.144   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
193.173.28.142  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp8s0
```

VM routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure what VPN you are using, but this is a known issue and I don't think there any work around - however you can use " route -n add" command to connect to vboxnet only after disconnecting from VPN, please look at the [Ticket #14293](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14293)